# Implement redirects properly for SEO in Angular

Tags: seo, google-search, angular

I'm developing a website where it's really important, that the subpages of the site are indexed properly in Google.

A few months ago, we changed the url structure, we added a `/<language>/` after the TLD (for example, the old link was `https://test.org/article/3919939` and the new is `https://test.org/de/article/3919939`).

The page is written in Angular 7.

I implemented a redirect component, so that if you go to `/article/3919939/`, it redirects you to `/de/article/3919939`. The problem now is that Google still indexes still the old links. They aren't in the sitemaps any more, but Google still finds and indexes them and marks them as "discovered, not in sitemap". How can I set it up properly so Google takes the correct link and not the wrong one? Do I have to remove the redirect component, so the old links don't work anymore?

Comment: How did you implement the redirects?  Are they Angular routes (js redirects) or 301 permanent redirects implemented in .htaccess?

Comment: As for the tags, is version 8 no longer part of Angular.js?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller In general, the term angular.js is only used for the original angular framework (until version 2), anything above is just called Angular (So basically since 2016). I just wanted to make sure that I'm not talking about the original Angular.JS. 

The redirects are made in a Angular component, since I have to add the language part of the URL. I neither use 301 permanent redirects nor the angular routing. I just replaced all components with my new "RedirectComponent" in the Angular routing.

Comment: I'd bet you'd have better luck implementing the redirects in .htaccess.   Angular doesn't support SEO very well.   Redirects implemented inside Angular aren't going to be good for SEO.